# Get MP4 video from response header with Javascript

Tags: html, html5-video

Rright now the video is playing HTML and is downloadable using HTML5  video play:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But the link which I have is a pointer to the path of the file not the actual path.

My question is how can I create an MP4 file with the content playing the video player so it possible to create a download link or just get the actual path of the video?

Below is the response header -*SOME number ARE changed by ME*-

```
accept-ranges: bytes
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
cache-control: private, max-age=21257
client-protocol: quic
content-length: 7998281
content-type: video/mp4
date: Sat, 23 Mar 2019 07:39:56 GMT
expires: Sat, 23 Mar 2019 07:39:56 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 20:29:28 GMT
server: gvs 1.0
status: 200
x-content-type-options: nosniff

:authority: r6---sn-nv47ln7e.googlevideo.com
:method: GET
:path: /videoplayback?key=cms1&txp=5531432&c=WEB&sparams=clen,dur,ei,expire,gir,id,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,lmt,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source&lmt=15483617368343385&clen=7998281&expire=1553348353&ipbits=0&requiressl=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&dur=283.910&itag=18&ip=1*2.**.9**247&gir=yes&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&pl=22&id=o-AIvlmeUUJEzPSZWM9f8YqH5XvnSYMT86D7zzXmF70xuH&ei=oeKVXOnVL4f8kgbK7K7wCg&fvip=6&signature=4683A5D51C959CC1CEF27E1354F27F11A05703B5E83.4713B7A37AF177E89DE5FF91DF755BAC2A983026&title=50Cent+feat.+Eminem+-+Patiently+Waiting+[HD]+/w+Lyrics&redirect_counter=1&rm=sn-o09ld7e&req_id=f01e93eea06736e2&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mip=**.**.***.***&mm=31&mn=sn-nv47ln7e&ms=au&mt=1553326620&mv=m
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
```

Comment: What is that the response headers from, exactly? It's unclear. If you want a download link, just make a hyperlink to the same URL you give in the "src" of the video tag. I'm unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: i made a website that downloads videos from instagram youtube and facebook,my problem is i am still get a pointer to the file which is playable in html video player and can be downloaded through chrome html video play,how can i get the mp4 file from the video player, you can check my website http://socialvideo-downloader.com/

Comment: I'm not going to read your whole website but I'm going to guess by "pointer" you're talking about a stream? So maybe it can only be streamed from those sites rather than downloaded. And you didn't answer my question about headers...what request are those headers the response to?

Comment: If you want some more specific help then paste some relevant code here as well, not just a generic example from documentation

Comment: https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.9040-2/10000000_416675425462968_3039308275297288192_n.mp4?_nc_cat=110&efg=eyJybHIiOjcwMCwicmxhIjoyMzM1LCJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9zZCJ9&rl=700&vabr=389&_nc_ht=video-yyz1-1.xx&oh=296be4ba6ba02b994fd88b9586d19a0d&oe=5C96261B#t=0.1

Comment: i am sorry but i am a newbie in this thing.. the link upove will play a will give a video which is downloadable with html video player in chrome,the only thing is that how can i get the mp4 link of the video

Comment: if you're trying to build a tool that will allow you to download other people's videos from various sites, you're going to struggle. Most of the ones you list have a number of measures in place to make that difficult

Comment: i already did that, i am left with how to get the content as mp4